# Multiple WHERE with LIMIT MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP, is it possible to select multiple rows from one table, in a MySQL database, with different WHERE clauses having a specific LIMIT for each WHERE clause.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE color = 'blue' LIMIT 5 OR color = 'red' LIMIT 10
```

I know the above statement does not work. But is there a way to do this with a single call to the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), if I understand your post correctly:

```
(SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE color = 'blue' LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE color = 'red' LIMIT 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE color = 'blue' LIMIT 5

UNION

SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE color = 'red' LIMIT 10 ;
```

Comment: Will not work without () to delimit queries, LIMIT 10 will apply to both result

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official MySQL documentation regarding subqueries (there's a reference made to LIMITs here, and some cases they may not be valid in): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-restrictions.html -- you may find an optimisation using subqueries in there, but UNION is probably quite fast and will probably be auto-optimised.

Answer (score -1):

I believe [flow control in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) is what you're looking for.